# Read-only filesystem => boot hangs

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, read-only, reboot

From time to time, I encounter a situation where my remote Ubuntu Linux server (18.04 LTS) experiences disk IO errors, resulting in the filesystem becoming read-only. While I can SSH into the server and attempt to reboot it, the reboot process hangs indefinitely. Typically, I resolve this issue by physically accessing the server, connecting it to a screen and keyboard, and quickly reviving it. If I recall correctly, during the boot sequence, the server enters a maintenance mode, allowing me to fix the disk by running fsck, after which subsequent reboots proceed smoothly.

However, I am currently away from home. Despite running fsck and addressing all errors while the filesystem was in a read-only state, the server hanged during the reboot process even though the disk is now repaired. Consequently, I anticipate that the server will remain offline until my return.

I am seeking advice on how to handle similar situations more effectively in the future. Specifically, I would like to know how to prevent the server from entering maintenance mode or ensure that SSH remains active during this state. Any guidance or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Get disks that doesn't fail?

Comment: you could try `reboot -f` but really the solution to a broken disk is a new disk

Answer (score 0):

To forcefully reboot a Linux machine, you can use [the Sys Req hacks](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysrq.html)

If you can SSH into the machine, try issuing `echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger`

*Note: this forces an immediate reboot, without even trying to sync disks.*